# For wcscmp() and wcscoll() are wide-character comparison. What is differences?

Tags: c, function, unicode

For wcscmp() and wcscoll() are wide-character comparison. 
What is differences ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `wcscoll` will interpret the parameters as appropriate to the `LC_COLLATE` category of the current locale.

If local is not an issure, `wcscmp` functions should be used, especially with large wstrings for performance.

Comment: thank,wcscoll is comparison to locale ,wcscmp is binary comparison to fast

Answer (score 1):

From an [IBM technical reference](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/aix/v7r1/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.aix.basetechref/doc/basetrf2/wcscoll.htm):

> **Note**: The **wcscoll** subroutine differs from the **wcscmp** subroutine in
>   that the **wcscoll** subroutine compares wide characters based on their
>   collation values, while the wcscmp subroutine compares wide characters
>   based on their ordinal values. The **wcscoll** subroutine uses more time
>   than the **wcscmp** subroutine because it obtains the collation values
>   from the current locale.

For more on collation functions:
http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Collation-Functions.html